# prevent functions declared __attribute__((constructor)) to be called

Tags: c, linux, gcc, ld

I need to use a 3rd party lib that performs some global initializations in a function declared `__attribute__((constructor))` thus which is executed on load.

Doing so, this function accesses some resources (say network) which are not yet available and fails.

I would like to prevent this call to be done 'on load' to be able to perform it 'on demand' when I know all is ready.

Using dlopen at runtime is not really an option because it would cause to rewrite quite a lot of code.

Comment: What from the 3rd party lib do  you have access to? You have a header with the function declarations with the constructor attribute. Can you redefine the function in your code to replace the call that is causing problems?

Comment: well, the function is actually declared in a header of the lib yes. You mean forcing my symbol instead of the lib's one?

Comment: Yes, that was what I was thinking. Say you have a header with `void construct1 () __attribute__ ((constructor (101)));` Then you could define your own `void construct1() { int *stub; (void)stub; }` and just let the constructor run doing nothing. (note: I haven't tried replacing a constructor, but just as you can overwrite system declarations -- you should be able to do that for the library)

Comment: Well, I'll give it a try, I need to call the original one later, but I guess I can do that with dlsym(RTLD_NEXT), to be continued... :)

Comment: update, this actually worked, you should write an answer so that I validate your proposal.

Comment: Will wonders never cease! I'm glad that worked for you. There isn't a lot of documentation here, so you are more or less just using an understanding of how the compiler does things to make a SWAG (swinging wild-add guess) at what "should" work. I'll have to look over some additional documentation to be able to write an answer based on more than a good old swag `:)` I'll do that after I get some shuteye.